# Android application || CPU investigation

Tags: android, cpu-usage

I have installed an Android application from the Market that has a high CPU rate,
and would like to investigate what is causing that.

Currently I already know from adb shell that the application usage is 20% (avarage) of the CPU. (the command by the way is "top -m 5 -d 1")

Since i haven't written the code i don't have the actual project. 
Is there a possibly to see what sub_module is causing the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by going into adb shell.
The command top -m 5 -s cpu -t gave me what i asked.

See command information:

**Usage: top [ -m max_procs ] [ -n iterations ] [ -d delay ] [ -s sort_column ] [ -t ] [ -h ]**

```
-m num  Maximum number of processes to display.
-n num  Updates to show before exiting.
-d num  Seconds to wait between updates.
-s col  Column to sort by (cpu,vss,rss,thr).
-t      Show threads instead of processes.
-h      Display this help screen.
```